# Delete Button deletes the item before the targeted item

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been creating a To Do List and it has two buttons per one entry which is Done to line-through finished tasks and Remove to delete it. And when I delete second item it deletes first instead of second. How can I fix this?
Thank You.

Here's the HTML

```
<body>
<header>
    <h1>To Do List</h1>
    <div class="addItems">
        <input type="text" name="text" id="addThis" onfocus="this.value=''">
        <input type="button" value="Add" id="addBtn">
    </div>
</header>

<section class="checkList">
    <ul class="list"></ul>
    
</section>
```

Here's the JS

```
addButton.addEventListener('click' , add);

function add(){
    let input = document.getElementById('addThis').value;
    let newLi = document.createElement('li');
    newLi.id = "listNewItem";
    newLi.style.listStyleType = "none";
    newLi.style.backgroundColor = "#f4f4f4";
    newLi.style.padding = "10px";
    newLi.style.marginBottom = "10px";
    newLi.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input));
    let deleteBtn = document.createElement('button')
    console.log(newLi);
    let list = document.querySelector('.list');
    list.insertBefore(newLi, list.childNodes[2]);

    let delBtn = document.createElement('button');
    delBtn.id = "doneButn";
    delBtn.className = "delete";
    delBtn.setAttribute("onclick" , "done()");
    delBtn.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Remove"));
    newLi.appendChild(delBtn);

    let doneSubBtn = document.createElement('button');
    doneSubBtn.id = "alreadyDone";
    doneSubBtn.className = "done";  
    doneSubBtn.setAttribute("onclick" , "finished()");
    doneSubBtn.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Done"));
    newLi.appendChild(doneSubBtn);
}

function done(){
        let del = document.getElementById('doneButn');
        let li = del.parentNode;
        li.remove();
}

function finished(){
    let liText = document.getElementById('alreadyDone').parentNode;
    liText.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have more elements with the same ID (`doneButn`) - then the first one is targeted (ID haas to be unique).

Use function param to tell JS which element should be targeted.

```
delBtn.setAttribute("onclick" , "done(this)");
                                      ^^^^
... 
function done(el){
        //    ^^
    let li = el.parentNode;
        //   ^^
    li.remove();
}
```